# The best way to load an openstreetmap .osm in a docker-container

Tags: python-3.x, xml, simulation, openstreetmap, docker-container

**My intentions:**

Actually, I intend to:

- implement vehicles as containers
- simulate/move these containers on the .osm maps-based roads

**My viewpoint about the problem:**

I have loaded the `XML-based` `.osm` file and processed it in python using `xml.dom`. But I am not satisfied with the performance of loading the `.osm` file because later on, I will have to add/create more vehicles as containers that will be simulated onto the same road.

**Suggestions needed:**
This is my first time to solve a problem related to maps. In fact, I need suggestions on how to proceed by keeping in mind, the performance/efficiency, with this set of requirements. Suggestions in terms of implementation will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simulating lots of vehicles by running lots of docker containers in parallel? So you're initialising the same image with different start locations etc passed in as ENV vars? Sounds like an interesting docker experiment (but probably not justifiable otherwise) Do you have a central thing for holding and sharing the state (positions of other vehicles)? It doesn't seem like the bit where you load a .osm file into some sort of database or internal map representation is going to be the most complicated or the most performance critical part of this.

Comment: @HarryWood, thanks for the response. Yes, simulating containers in parallel. Yes, I will use a start/destination location by selecting a random location [latitude, longitude] on the map (which will be a from an array having different locations). Yes, I would have a central database onto which each vehicle will have to update their current locations after every specific interval of time. Yes, you're right about loading the .osm file place actually. I have seen the Follium recently,

Comment: @HarryWood, is there a way to generate the vehicle next location [latitude, latitude] such a way that it stays on the road/way. (I mean to say how to keep the vehicle on track of the road).

Comment: I'm thinking you'll probably want to do "routing" through the road network (taking account of one ways etc?), giving your agents a purposeful path to follow to a destination. Rather than a country scaled server-based system you might find something lightweight like the code of the JOSM routing plugin more useful. Then working backwards from a calculated route you can find interpolated steps along that path.

Comment: Yes Mr. @HarryWood, that (routing) is what exactly I intend to do. I will definitely like to search for the JOSM routing plugin. Your comments are really helpful and I was planning to give some credit in the form of accepting and voting up your answer if you post an answer. I really appreciate your support. Thanks very much. In the future, I will post more questions related to this stuff. Actually, I am in the process of developing a project/blueprint for the Linux Foundation’s community named as Akraino!!!

Comment: yeah alright. I have re-post my comments as an "answer" (with some more links)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulating lots of vehicles by running lots of docker containers in parallel might work I suppose. Maybeyou're initialising the same image with different start locations etc passed in as ENV vars? As a practical way of doing agent simulations this sounds a bit over-engineered to me, but as an interesting docker experiment it might make sense.

Maybe you'll need a central thing for holding and sharing the state (positions of other vehicles) and serving that back to the multiple agents.

The challenge of loading an .osm file into some sort of database or internal map representation doesn't seem like the hardest part, and because it may be done once on initialisation and imagine it's not the most performance critical part of this.

I'm thinking you'll probably want to do "routing" through the road network (taking account of one ways etc?), giving your agents a purposeful path to follow to a destination. This will get more complicated if you want to model interactions with other agents e.g. you might want to model getting stuck in traffic because other agents are going the same way, and even decisions to re-route because of traffic, so you may want quite a flexible routing system, perhaps self-coded.

But there's lots of open source routing systems which work with OSM data, to at least draw inspiration from. See this list: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing#Developers

Popular choices like [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org) are designed to scale up to country size or even global openstreetmap data, but I imagine that's overkill for you (you're probably looking at simulating within a city road network?). Even so. Probably easy enough to get working in a docker container.

Or you might find something lightweight like the code of the [JOSM routing plugin](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/Routing) easier to embed in your docker image and customize (although I see that's using a library called "JGraphT")

[image]

Then working backwards from a calculated route you can calculate interpolated steps along that path which will allow you to make your simulated agents take a step on each iteration (simulated movement)

Comment: thanks for the response. Yes, simulating containers in parallel. Yes, I will use a start/destination location by selecting a random location [latitude, longitude] on the map (which will be a from an array having different locations). Yes, I would have a central database onto which each vehicle will have to update their current locations after every specific interval of time. Yes, you're right about loading the .osm file place actually. I have seen the Follium recently.

Comment: Yes Mr. @HarryWood, that (routing) is what exactly I intend to do. I will definitely like to search for the JOSM routing plugin. Your comments are really helpful and I was planning to give some credit in the form of accepting and voting up your answer if you post an answer. I really appreciate your support. Thanks very much. In the future, I will post more questions related to this stuff. Actually, I am in the process of developing a project/blueprint for the Linux Foundation’s community named as Akraino!!!